# APC & Wordpress: Server down if enable APC

Tags: php, wordpress, apc

Some basic information:

Linux: 2.6.32 (64bit)

PHP: 5.4.15

Apache: 2.4.4

MySQL: 5.6.11

APC: 3.1.9

Wordpress: 3.5.1, with Woocommerce(2.0.10)

The problem is, when I enable APC, the following errors occur:

```
Warning: register_shutdown_function(): Invalid shutdown callback 'wpdb::__destruct' passed in /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 537

Fatal error: Call to undefined method wpdb::init_charset() in /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 542
```

Here is my APC config in php.ini:

```
[APC]
; Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php
extension=apc.so

apc.enabled=1

apc.shm_segments=1

; 32MB per Wordpess install.  Ref: http://gregrickaby.com/the-perfect-apc-configuration/
apc.shm_size=320M

;Relative to the number of cached files (you may need to watch your stats for a day or two to find out a good number)
apc.num_files_hint=10000

;Relative to the size of WordPress
apc.user_entries_hint=10000

;The number of seconds a cache entry is allowed to idle in a slot before APC dumps the cache
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.gc_ttl=3600

;Setting this to 0 will give you the best performance, as APC will
;not have to check the IO for changes. However, you must clear 
;the APC cache to recompile already cached files. If you are still
;developing, updating your site daily in WP-ADMIN, and running W3TC
;set this to 1
apc.stat=1

;This MUST be 0, WP can have errors otherwise!
apc.include_once_override=0

;Only set to 1 while debugging
apc.enable_cli=0

;Allow 2 seconds after a file is created before it is cached to prevent users from seeing half-written/weird pages
apc.file_update_protection=2

;Leave at 2M or lower. WordPress does't have any file sizes close to 2M
apc.max_file_size=2M

;Ignore files
apc.filters = "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/apc.php,/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/phpinfo.php,wp-cache-config"

apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.use_request_time=1
apc.slam_defense=0
;apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.stat_ctime=1
apc.canonicalize=1
apc.write_lock=1
apc.report_autofilter=0
apc.rfc1867=0
apc.rfc1867_prefix =upload_
apc.rfc1867_name=APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_freq=0
apc.rfc1867_ttl=3600
apc.lazy_classes=0
apc.lazy_functions=0
apc.file_md5=0
```

Here are some combination of what I tried:

```
apc.stat = 0, apc.stat_ctime=0

apc.stat = 1, apc.stat_ctime=1

apc.stat = 0, apc.stat_ctime=1

apc.stat = 0, apc.stat_ctime=0
```

However, APC still cannot be used.  Only when I disable APC, the site works properly.

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem?

Thank you in advance.

[APC config in image](http://i1193.photobucket.com/albums/aa345/alucard0011/apc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Probably APC does not interpret that syntaxis of register_shutdown_function correctly. There are two ways of defining static method callbacks with this function:

1. `register_shutdown_function('someClass::someMethod');`
2. `register_shutdown_function(array('someClass', 'someMethod'));`

You could refer to the documantation and commetns for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: Thank you.  But it does not solve my problem.  I saw the code in wpdb.php, it is using: 

register_shutdown_function(array('someClass', 'someMethod'));

Here is how I solve it: I upgrade APC to 3.1.13.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress also worked for me when I disabled apc from php.ini